# Obtaining the path of a process in Java

Tags: java, unix, process, system-calls

I am experimenting with placing the UNIX streams `stdout` and `stderr` into JavaFX text areas.  Here is the code I have created

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;
public class SystemCallsGUI extends javafx.application.Application
{
    TextArea stdout;
    TextArea stderr;
    TextField commandField;

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        stdout = new TextArea();
        stderr = new TextArea();
        commandField = new TextField();
    };
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primary)
    {
        VBox contents = new VBox();
        contents.getChildren().addAll(
            new Label("Enter Command"),
            commandField,
            new Label("Standard  Output"),
            stdout,
            new Label("Standard Error"),
            stderr);
        Scene s = new Scene(contents, 500, 600);
        commandField.setOnAction( e ->
        {
            doCommand(commandField.getText());
            commandField.setText("");
        });
        primary.setScene(s);
        primary.show();
    }
    public void doCommand(String command)
    {
        try
        {
            //Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            String[] pieces = command.split("\\s");
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pieces);
            Process p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader stdinReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stderrReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            String line = "";
            StringBuffer bag = new StringBuffer();
            while( (line = stdinReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                bag.append(line + "\n");
            }
            stdout.setText(stdout.getText() + bag);
            bag = new StringBuffer();
            while( (line = stderrReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                bag.append(line + "\n");
            }
            stderr.setText(stderr.getText() + bag);
            Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
            String wd = env.get("cwd");
            System.out.println(wd);
            //System.setProperty("user.dir", newDir);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException death");
        }
    }
}
```

I would like for the `cwd` of this Java process to follow  that of the underlying shell, so if I type, for example `cd` the myhome directory becomes the `cwd` of the java process.  Is this possible or is it an inherent security violation in Java?

Comment: I have shown the specific  problem I am trying to solve.  I am unsure if it has a reasonable solution.

Comment: What underlying shell? You are running one or more commands here, not a shell. Even if there were a shell, cwd is never an env var; for *some* shells it is a *shell* (internal) var. And `ProcessBuilder.environment` is the initial environment passed *to* a child process without any subsequent modification.

Comment: The shell that is the parent of this program.

Comment: Assuming 'this program' is the process running your Java code, its parent doesn't have to be a shell and doesn't have to still exist; if it is and does, its environment is *never* affected by anything done by the Java code or jvm or any subprocess you run from Java. The parent's environment *might* change as result of other things you didn't do, and *if* you are on Linux or Solaris *and* access is not restricted you can see those unrelated changes by looking in the (pseudo)file `/proc/$ppid/environ` using the ppid from `/proc/self/status`.

Comment: Adding: you can't change the actual working directory of the Java (jvm) process, but  `ProcessBuilder` can give a *subprocess* any working directory you choose, which could be from the parent's env var.

Comment: I would like for cd to make its directory visible.  Right now, this can't "hear" cd commands.

Comment: If by 'cd command' you mean running the `cd` *program* (using `ProcessBuilder` or equivalent) that is totally useless: it changes the directory for the `cd` process which immediately exits, with no effect on anything else; see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/why-is-cd-not-a-program for why a *shell* handles `cd` as a builtin -- but you aren't using a shell.